# Get select option including HTML element using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-select

I have one select input with some options. For example,

```
<select id="myArea">
    <option class="myClass_1" style="color:red;" value="1">Area 1</option>
    <option class="myClass_2" style="color:green;" value="2">Area 2</option>
    <option class="myClass_1" style="color:red;" value="3">Area 3</option>
    <option class="myClass_1" style="color:red;" value="4">Area 4</option>
</select>
```

Now I want to iterate over the select and get all the options elements with attributes like `class,style`,etc., I tried to get this using `.html()`. but it doesn't work.

```
var optionStr = '';
$('#myArea option').each(function() {

    optionStr += $(this).html(); // like <option class="myClass_1" style="color:red;" value="1">Area 1</option>, etc.,

});
```

Expected Output:

```
optionStr = '<option class="myClass_1" style="color:red;" value="1">Area 1</option><option class="myClass_2" style="color:green;" value="2">Area 2</option><option class="myClass_1" style="color:red;" value="3">Area 3</option><option class="myClass_1" style="color:red;" value="4">Area 4</option>';
```

How should I get this? which `jQuery-selectors` I have to use?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access [`outerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML) property

```
var optionStr = '';
$('#myArea option').each(function() {
    optionStr += this.outerHTML; 
});
```

```js
var optionStr = '';
$('#myArea option').each(function() {
    optionStr += this.outerHTML; 
});
console.log(optionStr)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="myArea">
    <option class="myClass_1" style="color:red;" value="1">Area 1</option>
    <option class="myClass_2" style="color:green;" value="2">Area 2</option>
    <option class="myClass_1" style="color:red;" value="3">Area 3</option>
    <option class="myClass_1" style="color:red;" value="4">Area 4</option>
</select>
```

---

However you can also get the `html()` of parent select('myArea') element

```
var optionStr = $('#myArea').html();
```

```js
var optionStr = $('#myArea').html();
console.log(optionStr)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="myArea">
    <option class="myClass_1" style="color:red;" value="1">Area 1</option>
    <option class="myClass_2" style="color:green;" value="2">Area 2</option>
    <option class="myClass_1" style="color:red;" value="3">Area 3</option>
    <option class="myClass_1" style="color:red;" value="4">Area 4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: `outerHTML` worked perfectly and i have to validate on `each` iteration. that would be better. thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$('#myArea').html()` to get all the options:

```js
console.log($('#myArea').html());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="myArea">
  <option class="myClass_1" style="color:red;" value="1">Area 1</option>
  <option class="myClass_2" style="color:green;" value="2">Area 2</option>
  <option class="myClass_1" style="color:red;" value="3">Area 3</option>
  <option class="myClass_1" style="color:red;" value="4">Area 4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I knew this will work. I have some validation's on each iteration. Satpal answer is work perfectly. thanks for your response. :)

Comment: good to know you got help from this community and you are welcome @Ranjith